# Python: How do I lock an object until all threads have done a thing

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a simple threaded server that will send a message to all clients.  I have an object that is reset after posting the change message, however I am having a hard time figuring out how to reset that object only after all threads have posted the change message.

To add some context to the problem.  I am building a multi user Tkinter python app which connects to a remote database to retrieve information and the application needs to know when data changes so that when a user updates data, all other running instances of the app will get the update. From what I understand, MySQL does not support asynchronous application updates.  Instead of running a query every 5 seconds on the database to see if there is a change,  I am putting this code server side so that it will send a message to a socket on the client that a change has occurred on the database.

The main loop is just a dummy that will simulate a change

Here is my code:

```
import socket, threading, time, select, os

class dbMonitor:
   isDBAltered = False
   def postChange(self):
       self.isDBAltered = True
   def __str__(self):
        return str(self.isDBAltered)


class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, port,dbMon):
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        self.sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), self.port))
        self.dbMon = dbMon


    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(100)
        read_list = [self.sock]
        while True:
            read,write,error = select.select(read_list,[],[],1)
            for s in read:
                if s is self.sock:
                    client, address = self.sock.accept()
                    client.settimeout(60)
                    threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient, args = (client,address)).start()
    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        read_list = [client]
        size = 1024
        while True:
            response = b'Ack'
            if self.dbMon.isDBAltered:
                response = b'CHANGE'
                try:
                    client.send(response)
                except:
                    client.close()
                    return False
                self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False

            read,write,error = select.select(read_list,[],[],1)
            for s in read:
                if s is client:
                    try:
                        data = client.recv(size)
                        print(data)
                        if data:

                             client.send(response)
                        else:
                            raise error('Client disconnected')
                    except:
                        client.close()
                        return False

def mainLoop():

    while True:
        time.sleep(15)
        print(dbMon)
        dbMon.postChange()

dbMon = dbMonitor()
server = ThreadedServer(5005,dbMon)
threading.Thread(target = mainLoop, args=()).start()
threading.Thread(target = server.listen(), args=()).start()
```

How do I get `self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False` to execute only after all threads have executed:

```
response = b'CHANGE'
                try:
                    client.send(response)
```

Comment: Look into the `join` function: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join

Comment: From what I understand, the `join` function is used to wait for all threads to finish.  My threads are not terminating, they are just doing a thing then going on about their business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to synchronize something that's asynchronous... This is massively more complicated than it should be. Your dbmon is only storing a boolean flag... why not just asynchronously modify the "database" instead? For example, if the "database" was a thread-safe buffer, you could just append to that buffer or modify that buffer without synchronizing each thread individually, pull the information written to that buffer and write it to the client socket they belong to in another event loop (this is pretty much what asyncore does)

That said, I have some (probably nonworking, but I hope you get the idea) reference modified code for you to go off of if you want to continue pursing this avenue.

Basically, dbmon will keep a mapping of thread ids to [creation time, modified flag]

Our predicate returns true iff all threads created before a certain threshold have ALL set the modified flag. We set the modified flag when we send the response in the data = client.recv(size) portion of your code. And then we wait on that condition in the server send. We keep notifying all waiting threads on each client receive so that when the condition is finally met, our waiting server threads will all unblock and send the subsequent response.

```
import socket, threading, time, select, os
import collections

class dbMonitor:
   def __init__(self):
       self.isDBAltered = {}
       self.lock = threading.Lock()
   def newThread(self, tid):
       self.lock.acquire()
       # time of creation, boolean whether that thread has sent response
       self.isDBAltered[tid] = [time.time(), False] 
       self.lock.release()
   def threadDone(self, tid):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.isDBAltered.pop(tid, None)
        self.lock.release()
    def altered(self, tid):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.isDBAltered[tid][1] = True
        self.lock.release()
    def reset(self, tid):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.isDBAltered(tid)[1] = False
        self.lock.release()
   def __str__(self):
        return str(self.isDBAltered)


class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, port,dbMon):
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        self.sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), self.port))
        self.dbMon = dbMon
        self.lock = threading.lock()
        self.cv = threading.Condition()
        self.thresh = 2000

    def condition_pred(self):
        # unblock if threads currently running for longer than self.thresh have all set their flags
        return all([timecreate[1] if time.time() - timecreate[0] > self.thresh else True for tid,timecreate in self.dbMon.isDBAltered])

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(100)
        read_list = [self.sock]
        while True:
            read,write,error = select.select(read_list,[],[],1)
            for s in read:
                if s is self.sock:
                    self.lock.acquire()
                    client, address = self.sock.accept()
                    client.settimeout(60)
                    T = threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient, args = (client,address)).start()
                    self.dbmon.newThread(T.ident)
                    self.lock.release()
    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        read_list = [client]
        size = 1024
        while True:
            response = b'Ack'
            with self.cv:
                self.cv.wait_for(self.condition_pred)
                self.dbMon.reset(threading.get_ident())
                response = b'CHANGE'
                try:
                    client.send(response)
                except:
                    client.close()
                    self.dbmon.threadDone(threading.get_ident())
                    return False

            read,write,error = select.select(read_list,[],[],1)
            for s in read:
                if s is client:
                    with self.cv:
                        try:
                            data = client.recv(size)
                            print(data)
                            if data:
                                 client.send(response)
                                 self.dbMon.altered(threading.get_ident())
                                 self.cv.notifyAll()
                            else:
                                raise error('Client disconnected')
                        except:
                            client.close()
                            self.dbmon.threadDone(threading.get_ident())
                            return False
```

Comment: I was actually just reading that doc, but I am having some difficulty understanding how to define the condition.  My condition = all threads send response. When that condition is True, unblock and allow object state to be altered

Comment: @BryanFallin hm you'll need to use a semaphore in that case, or define a predicate that is true if and only if all threads send the response and use condition.wait_for()

Comment: @BryanFallin Actually. Your problem is you're trying to synchronize something that happens asynchronously. You'll never know how many threads are created, so you'll never know for certain if "all threads have sent a response" because threads can be created at ANY time. If you want to block any new threads UNTIL you execute self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False, that can be done. However you're ripe for deadlock conditions if you want to block BOTH self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False AND thread creation on that circular wait condition.

Comment: I see what you are saying.  In the context of the higher level project this is a part of, I only care about threads that have been alive past a certain time threshold.  In light of this, predicate is True if and only if threads alive greater than **_x_** seconds have sent the response.

Comment: @BryanFallin Okay, but your check for self.dbMon.isDBAltered and your setting self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False happens BEFORE you send the response... doesn't that seem a little circular to you? You want all threads to wait to execute self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False until they send a response, but all threads must execute self.dbMon.isDBAltered = False before they send a response.... I think you've got a little design error here.

Comment: As the code is right now, if more than one client connects to the server, only the last client to connect receives the message that a change occurred (and every subsequent change message) because the thread for that client changes the state of dbMon before the other threads get a chance to notify their respective clients.  I need every connected client to receive the message.  It is okay if a single client misses the first or even second change message.

Comment: I see what your saying,  send the message, then change the sate back to False. This is my first attempt at multithreading and sockets, so please bear with my ignorance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice,  I think I have failed to provide enough context for the situation I am faced with.  I have edited my initial post to add the missing context.  I have a bit of code that captures packets from the MySQL port and triggers on key words that make changes to the database.  I will have that bit of code set the flag on dbMon.  This is starting to feel a lot more complicated than it should be,  I just need all the connected clients to get the message that a change occurred on the database.  Maybe I am going about this the wrong way :/

Comment: gave credit for the help [project on GitHub](https://github.com/CEN3031-group16/GroupProject/blob/RemoteUpdates/serverScripts/mysqlport/threadServer.py)